# Готовый скрипт Pyautogui (автокликер по картинке) как прикрутить к нему Pyqt?

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyautogui

я совсем новичок, не могу никак понять, как интерфейс pyqt привязать к папке со скриптом, который ловит изображение по образцу.

```
import keyboard, pyautogui, os
from PyQt5 import uic
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication

Form, Window = uic.loadUiType("goldhunter.ui")

app = QApplication([])
window = Window()
form = Form()
form.setupUi(window)
window.show()


def on_click():
    print("Ловим сундуки...")

form.startwork.clicked.connect(on_click)

#app.exec()
files = os.listdir('syndyk')

while keyboard.is_pressed("Esc") == False:

    for f in files:

        picture = "syndyk/" + f

        button = pyautogui.locateOnScreen(picture, confidence = 0.95)

        if button:
            pyautogui.click(button)
            pyautogui.sleep(0.1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import sys
from threading import Thread 
import keyboard, pyautogui, os
from PyQt5 import uic
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication

Form, Window = uic.loadUiType("goldhunter.ui")

files = os.listdir('syndyk')

def thread():
    while keyboard.is_pressed("Esc") == False:

    for f in files:

        picture = "syndyk/" + f

        button = pyautogui.locateOnScreen(picture, confidence = 0.95)

        if button:
            pyautogui.click(button)
            pyautogui.sleep(0.1)

def on_click():
    print("Ловим сундуки...")
    Thread(target=thread).start()

app = QApplication([])
window = Window()
form = Form()
form.setupUi(window)
form.startwork.clicked.connect(on_click)
window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: Все работает. но мне нужно, чтобы скрипт запускался при нажатии на кнопку в графическом интерфейсе, а он запускается сразу

Comment: Обновил ответ, исправил скрипт.

Comment: Это на скорую руку, а так вообще необходимо использовать QThread.

Comment: не работает  :( запускается интерфейс, но по картинке не кликает после нажатия

Comment: Не кликает возможно не находит.

Comment: нет, тестировала с образцом картинки